# Change the colors of the pie chart in compouse (plot) in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, chart, plot

When using the new plot command available in QGIS 3.10 for compouse pie chart generation, I didn't find any option to change colors.
Is there any way to choose colors?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To control the color of the individual pie segments use an expression yielding color strings depending on the value in the Grouping field.

For example, to create a pie chart showing the population in each continent using the Natural Earth ne_110m_admin_0_countries layer, choose CONTINENT as the Grouping field and POP_EST as the Y field. Then, to set the colors for the pie segments use the following expression in the Marker color field:

```
map_get(
  map(
    'Asia', '#8dd3c7',
    'Europe', '#ffffb3',
    'North America', '#bebada',
    'South America', '#fb8072',
    'Africa', '#80b1d3',
    'Oceania', '#fdb462',
    'Antarctica', '#b3de69',
    'Seven seas (open ocean)','#fccde5'
  ), "CONTINENT"
)
```